# Link nodes of two JTree

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, treemap

[image: Jtrees in two panels in a frame]

i want to link the two nodes of a jtree ,one node of right jtree with a left node of jtree by a **solid line** in java swing.Please help me with some sample code to achieve this.

Please give me some useful sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're possibly going to need to draw on the glass pane.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane

Comment: i want to do it like http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_jamper/downloads/jamper/JamperRC1.1/JamperRC1_1.jar ......

Comment: that's built in java, could be fun to read through their source and see how they did it.  http://jamper.sourceforge.net/ screenshots

Comment: Have a look at http://jamper.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jamper/src/sqba/jamper/map/tree/ view the source for those two classes and you might get an idea.  They have overriden paintComponent() for JTree in MapperTree and delegated the painting of the links to the MapperTreeNode.  I still think the glasspane might be easier if you don't want to write custom paintComponent() code.

Comment: A bit more comment and I'll be done.  So what I think that jamper project has is three components side by side JTree, JPanel, JTree.  They did a bit of custom painting in the JTree to paint lines that go from the sides of the nodes to the middle JPanel.  Then they did a bunch of custom painting code to draw the middle panel with all the actual interesting graphics.

Comment: @soumitra chatterjee put JLabel (translucent by default) to the GlassPane and use paintComponent for draw Line ()

Comment: the glassPane is limited (and hard-to-use-correctly) in being per-rootPane. As of jdk7, there's JLayer for visual decoration (and event interception) of components

Comment: JLayer is awesome.  I haven't migrated to JDK 7 yet, so I use JXLayer and it's great.

Comment: Hmm, what?  You haven't continued the conversation.  Have you tried any of the proposals?  Have you rejected them all?  You need to say what you have tried and what the results were.

Comment: Do some experiments and see what works for you, that's the only way.  Downvoted because you aren't trying to find the solution, you seem to want it to be handed to you.  No more comments from me.